# No Method Found org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager()

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate-core-jakarta 5.6.15 It is throwining error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager()'
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.(SpringSessionContext.java:66)[image]
> ... 201 common frames omitted

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-net.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>${velocity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connection.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tokbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentok-server-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${opentok-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>${glassfish-javax-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ext-loggly</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.basjes.parse.useragent</groupId>
        <artifactId>yauaa</artifactId>
        <version>5.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${auth0.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nexmo</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>${jayway-json-path.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shield-solutions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-velocity-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-velocity-adapter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>${jayway-json-path.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.trajano.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${trajano-commons-testing.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`

Comment: Can you share the `pom.xml` file ?

Comment: Added  pom.xml Please check

Comment: You should remove dependencies which are already transitively included. You should mark dependencies `provided` when they are already provided by target runtime. Start removing the `jakarta.jakartaee-api` dependency, it's completely wrong to use that on Tomcat, especially in runtime scope.

Comment: Removed jakarta.jakartee-api but still error occuring

Comment: I really suggest you to run `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true` and after it you will be able to see the version miss configuration that you have.